# I don't understand the code in Ruby documentation that assigns a value within an if expression

Tags: ruby, documentation

Ruby documentation says:

```
if a = object.some_value #assigns a value
  # do something to a
end
```

But when running the above code I get a warning:

```
warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
```

Which implies that the example should actually be:

```
if a == object.some_value
  # do something to a
end
```

It is possible to assign a value to a variable in an `if` as shown above?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: if a = 3 It works with that, but it throws me a warning: "found = in conditional, should be ==" why would you warn me if the documentation tells me it's valid?

Comment: "why would you warn me if the documentation tells me it's valid" – Because not everything that is valid is a good idea. The condition part of a conditional expression is simply an expression, therefore it can contain anything an expression can contain: assignments, method definitions, class definitions, module definitions, loops, other conditional expressions. That doesn't mean it's a good idea, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two chunks of code are visually similar, but substantially different in intent. The first reads like this:

```
# Run object.some_value and capture the result into a
if a = object.some_value
  # ...
end
```

The second reads like this:

```
# If a is equivalent to the result of object.some_value
if a == object.some_value
  # ...
end
```

Where that's a *comparison* by virtue of `==`.

The capture form is often employed in a variety of cases, sometimes literally `case`, like where you'd capture the result of an awkward and/or slow chunk of code:

```
case (name = professor.name.to_s.split(/\s+/).last)
when "O'Reilly", "Berners-Lee"
  puts "Prof. %s is invited to the party." % name
else
  puts "Prof. %s is not invited to the party."
end
```

Where that `=` is a deliberate assignment so you can refer to `name` from that point forward instead of having to recompute that chunk.

Comment: One might argue that the first reads more like this: `a = object.some_value; if a; # ...;
end`. That makes it clear that `a` is to be assigned a value; written `if a = object.some_value`--which is done to save a line of code--has the disadvantage that the reader may feel obliged to to review the code to ensure that `==` was not intended.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It really depends on your coding conventions. If it's the first instance of `a` then it makes it more clear it's an intentional capture. That's why using a unique variable name helps.